# Change user account in google hangouts samsung s3 mini

Tags: google-account, google-hangouts

I've just signed up to Google Hangouts but am using a shared phone, as my friend already has an account and is logged in I don't know how to add an additional gmail address to switch accounts within the app...is this possible? If so how can I do it? Any other way I can access my Google Hangout on the phone if not?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new Google account from the main Settings app on the phone. On Samsung phones, choose the **Accounts** tab, then **Add account** and follow the steps as they come up. Once you've done this, the Hangouts app will show a *spinner* (drop-down box) to choose which account to use.

You might also wish to check the sync settings from the account settings. By default, when you add a new account it will also sync contacts, gmail, calendar items, &c. to the phone. If that's not what you want, you can turn off those items from the sync settings.